# Joomla add script from view to bottom of the head scripts

Tags: javascript, php, joomla

I would like to add this angular script:

```
<script src="/sitename/templates/templatename/app/modules/form/form.js"></script>
```

..to the bottom of the head scripts from the Joomla Nooku view my-account.html.php. Because in the template file there are the $doc->addScript()'s for adding scrips like AngularJS itself. So the custom script added in the view itself needs to be at the bottom.

How to do this?

If I use AddScript() in the view the script get added at the top of the head scripts.

I came up with a solution... well sort of. In the template file I specifiy the files that I would like to move to the bottom of the head scripts. Like this (a better solution/approach is welcome):

```
moveScriptToBottom($doc->_scripts, '/sitename/templates/templatename/app/modules/form/form.js');

function moveScriptToBottom(&$scripts, $src)
{
    foreach ($scripts as $key => $value) {
        if ($key === $src) {
            $move = $scripts[$key];
            unset($scripts[$key]);
            $scripts[$key] = $move;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no Joomla native way to do it, so the solution you came up with is more or less the only way to do it.

Comment: Well that's unfortunate.

Comment: @Floris you may want to take a look at the JED (http://extensions.joomla.org) to check if someone created an extension to better handle that.

Answer (score 1):

This will surely do it

```
<?php 
         //get the array containing all the script declarations
         $document = JFactory::getDocument(); 
         $headData = $document->getHeadData();
         $scripts = $headData['scripts'];

         //remove or add your script
         $scripts['/sitename/templates/templatename/app/modules/form/form.js']
         $headData['scripts'] = $scripts;
         $document->setHeadData($headData);
?>
```

Same way you can remove some un-wanted scripts by this

`unset($scripts['/media/system/js/mootools-core.js']);`

Comment: $headData['scripts'] seems to be an empty array in the view.html.php file :(

Comment: $headData = $doc->getHeadData();
$scripts = $headData['scripts'];
$scripts['/trainingtrips/templates/trainingtrips/teemr-app/modules/form/form.js'] = array(array ('mime' => '', 'defer' => '', 'async' => ''));
$headData['scripts'] = $scripts;
$doc->setHeadData($headData);
That code still adds the form.js to the top of the scripts in the head. I would like to add it to the bottom of the scripts in the head.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using "[addCustomTag](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Adding_JavaScript_and_CSS_to_the_page#Add_Custom_Tag)", Though it won't guarantee that the script tag will be added to the end of the page, still it will solve a lot of sequence issues with Joomla.

```
$doc->addCustomTag('<script src="' . JURI::root(true) . '/js/yourscript.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>');
```